# How do i access/pass variable from another view controller? It's not the next view controller, but the view controller after the next one in Swift

Tags: swift

The arrangement of segue of view controller is like this:

TakeAPicVC -> PickALanguageVC -> Play AudioVC

I want to display a picture from TakeAPicVC in PlayAudioVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegate and closure. 
If you never used, here you need.

```
// define delegate for PassPicture 
protocol PassPictureDelegate { 
  func getPicture() -> UIImage
}

// or you can use closure
typealias PassImageClosure = ((UIImage) -> Void)

class TakeAPicVC: UIViewController { 

  override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // when present next vc
    let picLanguageVC = PicALanguageVC()
    picLanguageVC.delegate = self

    /* use closure 
    picLanguageVC.passImageClosure?(you_pass_image_here)
    */
  }
}

extension TakeAPicVC: PassPictureDelegate { 
  func getPicture() -> UIImage { 
    return image // pass the picture here.
  }
}

class PickALanguageVC: UIViewController { 
  weak var delegate: PassPictureDelegate?

  // use closure.
  // -> var passImageClosure: PassImageClosure?

  // your playAudioVC
  var playAudioVC: PlayAudioVC!

  override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // when you initialize about this vc.
    playAudioVC = PlayAudioViewController()
    playAudioVC.delegate = delegate    

    /* use closure
    playAudioVC.passImageClosure = self.passImageClosure
    */ 
  }
}

class PlayAudioVC: UIViewController { 
  weak var delegate: PassPictureDelegate?
  // 2) closure 
  var passImageClosure: PassImageClosure?

  @IBOutlet weak var yourImageView: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourImageView.image = delegate?.getImage()

    /* use closure
    passImageClosure = { [weak self] image in 
      DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        self?.yourImageView.image = image
      }
    }
    */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and easy solution you could pass the image reference to the first `ViewController` and from there to the second one. So both ViewControllers, `PickALanguageVC` and `PlayAudioVC`, would hold the image reference.

Maybe not the most elegant solution from an architectural point of view but it could work for you.